Global VPN Datasets
I am looking for data sets related to VPNs on a global scale, with an incredibly broad set of guidelines. Sets of IP addresses associated with known VPNs, overall traffic analysis with focus on VPN statistics, geographical distribution of known servers, ratio of personal/private/public VPN offerings, etc. Pointers towards any data-centric research also appreciated.
